# Rails is calling the wrong gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

So, I've added the mysql2 gem by pasting the following line in my gemfilegem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.1'

But I get an error saying :

Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

I even tried using gem install mysql2, but i get the following error:
unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/

I changed the "https" to "http" in the gemfile, cause this solution seemed to work for a friend. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is what my database.yml file looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing an older version of the gem (I've found that 0.4.0 doesn't work). I'm assuming you are using one of the newer versions of Rails? I'm using Rails v. 4.2.1 and mysql2 v. 0.3.15 and it's working fine.

`gem 'mysql2', '0.3.15'` and `bundle` should fix this.

Comment: Thanks a ton :)
Ended up having to use a version older than this :P

Comment: Any time! I feel your pain, this problem wasted a half hour of my time a few weeks back.